Find multiple lines matching a helper-address string
I have a cisco ios configuration with several helper-address commands and I need to find all the helper-address lines at once with ciscoconfparse.
interface vlan 14
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.192
 ip helper-address 192.168.44.1
 ip helper-address 192.168.44.2
!
interface vlan 28
 ip address 192.0.2.65 255.255.255.192
 ip helper-address 10.10.44.1
 ip helper-address 10.10.44.2
!

I need to get the lines matching helper-address and associate them with the vlan that they are assigned to.  What is the best way to do this?

I found a way to do this with the re_list_iter_typed() command.
from ciscoconfparse2 import CiscoConfParse

parse = CiscoConfParse('config.txt')
for vlan_cmd in parse.find_objects('interface'):
    helper_addr_cmds = vlan_cmd.re_list_iter_typed('(ip helper-address \S+)')
    print("VLAN: ", vlan_cmd.split()[-1].strip())
    for helper in helper_addr_cmds:
        print("    HELPER ADDR:", helper.split()[-1])

That prints:
$ python get_helpers.py
VLAN: 14
    HELPER ADDR: 192.168.44.1
    HELPER ADDR: 192.168.44.2
VLAN: 28
    HELPER ADDR: 10.10.44.1
    HELPER ADDR: 10.10.44.2

